# ExCan't seem to get Xpath to work for finding specific nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a list of psychic readers inside an XML file, with lots of different bits of info about them.

I'm trying to call all psychic readers who have a particular skill, Astrology for example. So I have an xPath call like this:

```
$readers = reader_XML()->xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Skill='Astrology']");
```

But when I `var_dump($readers)`, it just returns an empty array. How can I make the line above, pull every reader that includes the Skill 'Astrology'?

An example of the XML is laid out like this:

```
<Reader>
    <Name></Name>
    <Description></Description>
    <Status></Status>
    <WebChatStatus></WebChatStatus>
    <WebCamStatus></WebCamStatus>
    <Pin></Pin>
    <PinTier>0</PinTier>
    <OverFlow>Yes</OverFlow>
    <Picture></Picture>
    <Pictures/>
    <PicturesLarge/>
    <Audio></Audio>
    <Rota/>
    <Categories>
        <Category name="Skills">
            <Skill>Clairvoyant</Skill>
            <Skill>Clairsentient</Skill>
            <Skill>Clairaudiant</Skill>
            <Skill>Life Coach</Skill>
            <Skill>Counsellor</Skill>
            <Skill>Psychic</Skill>
            <Skill>Reiki Healer</Skill>
        </Category>
        <Category name="Tools">
            <Skill>Astrology</Skill>
            <Skill>Numerology</Skill>
            <Skill>Tarot Cards</Skill>
        </Category>
        <Category name="Subjects">
            <Skill>Love/relationships</Skill>
            <Skill>Career/work</Skill>
            <Skill>Destiny/life path</Skill>
        </Category>
    </Categories>
    <Video></Video>
    <Rating></Rating>
    <StarSign/>
    <emailreader>No</emailreader>
</Reader>
```

Comment: `/ReaderDetails/Reader[.//Skill='Astrology']`

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work fine. Can you explain in an answer what the .// does exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you asking `/ReaderDetails/Reader[Skill='Astrology']`, xpath finds Skill as child of Reader. To say that it may be any descendant of Reader say it so:

```
/ReaderDetails/Reader[.//Skill='Astrology']
```